# Javascript and SQL Lite (multi browser offline SQL/database query)

Tags: javascript, sql, offline

I'm in the elections division of my county and am trying to simplify a voter lookup method for our poll judges during election time. Currently we are using a clunky heavy application that the judges must install, and we only support Windows. My goal is to have an offline (client-side) browser based solution that will work on any browser for any operating system.

I think, based on research that I've done through google searches and w3 forums, that I should be using JavaScript + SQL Lite. I have read that HTML5 has a good solution, but please keep in mind that election judges are typically elderly and don't upkeep their updates, or deviate from the preinstalled browser (typically IE), so HTML5 is not a plausible solution for our needs.

I've done a days worth of research on the subject and just come up empty handed, because honestly I'm NOT certain what I should be looking for. But as I said, the JS/SQLlite combo seems to be the solution. Unfortunately I can't find any tutorials that will help me reconcile these two systems. Do you have any suggestions? Anything is helpful at this point.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: My precinct uses hard copy print outs, sorted alpha by last name.  It takes about 5 seconds/voter to locate & cross out the name when they vote.  Without using a barcode reader, how can you improve on that?

Comment: Creating a JavaScript application, especially an offline application, which is compatible with a bunch of different browsers and browser versions is most most probably not easier than creating a cross platform desktop application for Windows, Linux and iOS.

Comment: How are you going to write to a SQLite database, particularly if legacy browsers need to be supported?  I agree with @DocBrown, you are probably better off with an actual desktop app.  If you really want to stick with web technologies, there are a few solutions such as node-webkit that would allow you to build a desktop app using HTML/JS, which could then be used w/phonegap for mobile.

Comment: @DanPichelman not sure how that comment is productive or answers my question, but I'm assuming you live in a precinct with 2 voters in it if it only takes your poll judges 5 seconds to check-in voters on paper.

Most helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Eric: I think Dan Pichelman was pretty serious. It may take 10 seconds, using a list with around 1000 to 2000 voters, but the whole process (which includes checking the ID card of the voter) does actually not last much longer than an electronic solution (for someone not trained using a keyboard using a computer will probably take longer). And the paper solution is much more reliable in case of a power loss.

Comment: @Eric - about 50,000 voters.  How fast can you find a word in a paper dictionary when you know how it is spelled?

Comment: @DanPichelman: 50,000 voters, all in *one* precinct? That's a complete city, seems many (not that one could not handle this assumed your staff is big enough).

Comment: @DocBrown erm, uh, darn it, you're right. The city's about 50,000.  Precinct is obviously smaller (which makes a paper solution work better)